# Delete numbers in a range under one condition

Tags: excel, vba

I consult them in this opportunity to know how to delete the numbers that are within a range if the value of a cell outside the working range is equal to zero. Image, example --》
in color the range of work

[image]

The value 7 is the number of numbers in the range. This number I calculate automatically with one formula.
The value -5 in the same way; Cells with text are counted with another formula. The value 2 is the difference between both calculations. What I want is that if value that is now 2 is equal to zero, delete all the numbers in the range.

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this? And where do you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] to see what makes a great question that gets quality answers.

Comment: @Alex de Jong I want to delete the numbers in the range automatically but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use VBA with and use a [SheetChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change), which triggers a code whenever the cell with value 2 in it is changing. In that Event, you can use an if-statement to check if the value of that cell is now 0.

If it is, loop through all the cells of the colored range and check if the cellvalue is not a number.
If it is not a number, remove the value of the cell.

I'm not going to write the code for you, but this will send you into the right direction to figure it out yourself I think.